# Update UI on added item to collection changed

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml

I'm using an `ObservableCollection` that is later on supposed to be filled with data coming in from a COM port, meaning it will be updated a lot. For testing purposes I setup design time sample data (which works fine) and runtime sample data, however I can't get my UI to update when adding items to my collection. I already managed to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` succesfully in my class that looks like this:

```
public class SensorViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public SensorViewModel()
    {
        dataItems = new ObservableCollection<SensorData>();
        dataItems.CollectionChanged += dataItems_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private ObservableCollection<SensorData> _dataItems;
    public ObservableCollection<SensorData> dataItems
    {
        get { return _dataItems; }
        set
        {
            _dataItems = value;
            // notify of changes
            NotifyPropertyChanged("dataItems");
            NotifyPropertyChanged("lastItem");
        }
    }

    public SensorData lastItem
    {
        get { return dataItems.Last(); }
    }

    public void LoadData()
    {
        dataItems.Add(new SensorData { id = 0, accelX = 0.231, accelY = 0.345, accelZ = -1.234 });
        dataItems.Add(new SensorData { id = 1, accelX = 1.231, accelY = 1.345, accelZ = -0.234 });
    }

    // handle property changes
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    void dataItems_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // get the sender observable collection
        ObservableCollection<string> obsSender = sender as ObservableCollection<string>;

        List<SensorData> editedOrRemovedItems = new List<SensorData>();

        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (SensorData newItem in e.NewItems)
            {
                editedOrRemovedItems.Add(newItem);
            }
        }

        if (e.OldItems != null)
        {
            foreach (SensorData oldItem in e.OldItems)
            {
                editedOrRemovedItems.Add(oldItem);
            }
        }

        // get the action which raised the collection changed event
        NotifyCollectionChangedAction action = e.Action;
    }
}
```

I create the DataContext on the MainWindow.xaml.cs and call `LoadData()` after that. However on my separate page called AccelData.xaml (subtab using ModernUI WPF project) the binding won't update. I'm binding it with `{Binding lastItem.accelX}`.

Do I need to somehow copy over the DataContext from the MainWindow to the subpage or am I simply not using the CollectionChanged event right? I just can't seem to get my binded value to appear at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You explicitly need to **raise `PropertyChanged` event for `lastItem`** in case you want it to be refreshed on UI.

Do it from collectionChanged handler:

```
void dataItems_CollectionChanged(object sender, 
                                 NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   ......
   NotifyPropertyChanged("lastItem");
}
```

---

Also your collectionChanged handler is not making any sense to me. Adding items in list and not using it anywhere.

Moreover **`obsSender` will always be null** because sender collection is of type `ObservableCollection<SensorData>` but your are typecasting it to `ObservableCollection<string>`.

```
// get the sender observable collection (THIS WILL BE NULL ALWAYS)
ObservableCollection<string> obsSender = sender as ObservableCollection<string>;
```

Comment: Yeah, excuse my pointless collectionChanged handler, I was experimenting with some code I found on StackOverflow, should've probably taken that out before posting. I had the idea of raising the event specifically there before as well, my main issue with that is however: `handler` is always `null`. Because of that the event is never even raised.

Comment: Okay, I thoroughly checked my DataContext and noticed I put SensorViewModel DataContext = new SensorViewModel() instead of DataContext = new SensorViewModel(). That fixed the issue of nobody subscribing to my event handler. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Three things:

1. I do not understand what you are doing in your CollectionChanged event. You are creating list and assigning items to that list and then doing nothing so your list is lost. Is this your intention?
2. I think you should change your binding. Instead of {Binding Path=lasItem.accelX} do something like: DataContext={Binding lastItem} Property(for example Text)={Binding accelX} .
3. And I think there's another possible bug with your code:

   dataItems.CollectionChanged += dataItems_CollectionChanged;

You are assigning event handler only once. When you are changing your ObservableCollection(what is possible because of public setter) you should remove event handler from old object and add event handler to new one.
Something like:

```
private ObservableCollection<SensorData> _dataItems;
public ObservableCollection<SensorData> dataItems
{
      get { return _dataItems; }
      set
      {
          if(_dataItems != null ) _dataItems.CollectionChanged -= dataItems_CollectionChanged;
          _dataItems = value;
          if(_dataItems != null ) _dataItems.CollectionChanged += dataItems_CollectionChanged;
          // notify of changes
          NotifyPropertyChanged("dataItems");
          NotifyPropertyChanged("lastItem");
      }
 }
```

Comment: As said above, excuse the nonsense CollectionChanged event. Your suggestion in rgeards of binding however causes a `System.NullReferenceException` (at design time that is). Makes me supect more and more that something is wrong with my `DataContext` handling.